# Get element in the same context of AngularJS directive (elements with same name, directive on several elements)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, directive

I have an issue with using the same directive on several elements.

What I want to do is return the selectedindex of the element in a specific directive context.

Example: Say I have 6 elements (same class) with the same directive. If I change the select option on one of these elements I want the directive to return the selectedindex of the one I changed.

Let's give code a go at clarifying:

```
function changeyvalue() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            scope.ifChangeSelect = function () {

                //Returns selectedindex of last inputfntsize.
                var a = $(element[0]).prop('selectedIndex');

                //Gets parent
                var selectIndex = $(element).parent();

                //Also returns selectedindex of last inputfntsize. 
                var getChildrenParent =    selectIndex.children('.inputFntSize').first().prop('selectedIndex');

                if (a == 0)
                {
                    alert("true");
                }

            }

        }
```

And say I have 6 elements that look like this, (but I also have several parent elements that look the same);

```
<select class="inputFntSize" changeyvalue ng-change="changeIfSelect()" ng-model="test.selectedFontSize" ng-options="fontsize for fontsize in test.fontsizes"></select>
```

Basically, I want the selectedindex to be returned of the element I change the value on, and not the last one created. Any ideas on how to do so?

Comment: try `scope: true` for your directive definition.

Comment: Thank you!

I thought scope:true was default for directives, but as I understand it scope:true creates a childscope with the parent as a prototype. Instead of the default which would use the parent scope directly.

Thanks :)